# Is it opposite-day today?

Tags: logic, language

Imagine, we had a very well-known day called opposite day, where everything is negated. Also imagine that you are walking along the street and someone asks you:

"Is it opposite-day today?"

What would be the correct answer, if it it is not opposite day on that day.

If you answer "no", the interpretation might be "it is opposite-day, since no is the opposite of yes". If you answer yes, it is opposite-day and you should have answered "no".

Also, you are not a liar.

And, to be fair, the question itself might be interpreted differently, as:

"Is it not opposite day not today" or "Isn't it not opposite-day not today" or .., but in this example case, the question stays the same.

What would be a non-ambiguous way for replying that simple question?

Comment: Description of the [SpongeBob episode about Opposite Day](http://spongebob.wikia.com/wiki/Opposite_Day) and [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcrjXmBgiFA)

Comment: That's the last question i would make if i wanted to know if it's oppositte day! :D. Now seriously, its not ambiguity its the fact that is not a one-to-one function: Q(o)=Q(!o)=false

Comment: Why not ask in the sky is blue (assuming a clear day)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on the well-known puzzle of the two brothers (one lies and one tells the truth, but you don't know which is which) and has the same general solution --you effectively have to route the answer through both conditions to arrive at a knowable truth state.

"No, and if this was opposite day, I would say the same."

In the case that it was opposite day, you would answer: "No, but if this was opposite day I would say that it was."

The "No" can be dropped, the key is that the second half of the statement ("I would tell the truth on opposite day") has a knowable truth value regardless of the current day.